# Is there any good alternative for pd.read_sas ? i'm facing few issues when loading huge amount of data from sas system to Jypter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, sas, data-analysis

Is there any good alternative for pd.read_sas ? i'm facing few issues when loading huge amount of data from sas system to  Jypter notebook.

Comment: what kind of issues?

Comment: This question is far too broad. Please provide more detail on what you're doing with the data and what the _few issues_ are that you're facing, this sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There are lots of problems with `pd.read_sas`; you may want to try the package `SAS7BDAT`, but that doesn't always work either because the SAS file format internals are not published

Comment: There seem to be some issue with date : start_date='30Dec2012'and end_date='01Dec2013' ' with df_this_week = pd.read_sas(in_file_this_week, format=None, index=None, encoding='latin1', chunksize=None, iterator=False), eg:

OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1915122.0 with the unit 'd'

Comment: However, it works for other files.

Comment: So you have one specific file that is having trouble?  Update the question with details of the file, the error and what attempts you have made to fix it.

Comment: The value 1,915,122 is probably not a real date or datetime value. It is too large for a date (06JUN7203) and as a datetime value is just before 4 AM on the 23rd  day (23JAN1960:03:58:42).  Tell read_sas to just treat that variable as a floating point number and then see if you can make heads or tails of it yourself.

Comment: @Tom how do i tell read_sas to treat it as a floating point number? (or as a string for that matter) the documentation does not list a whole lot of parameters for read_sas

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion

```
pyreadstat
```

is one of the most proper solutions. You can look at it here:

[Pyreadstat repo](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat)

I tried it few days ago and it seems to be promising, mainly because of processing time.

Example from doc.

```
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('/path/to/a/file.sas7bdat')

# done! let's see what we got
print(df.head())
print(meta.column_names)
print(meta.column_labels)
print(meta.number_rows)
print(meta.number_columns)
print(meta.file_label)
print(meta.file_encoding)
# there are other metadata pieces extracted. See the documentation for more details.
```